# Importing Excel sheet into Drool KIE Workbench and fill the data for rule template

Tags: excel, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have a scenario in Drools KIE Workbench 6.0. I have created a rule template through Guided Rule Template. Currently, the data to be filled for Guided Rule template is filled through manual under DATA tag in the workbench. Instead of filling data manually, I would like to import from Excel sheet data.

Is is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can import an Excel sheet and then convert it to a guided decision table.

Comment: Once its converted do you have to use the Guided Decision Table from then on  or can you switch between spreadsheets and guided tables?